# Mechanism of Pro*C compiler

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

I am new to Pro*C. I read that Pro*C compiler compiles your .pc file into .c (which is still a source file) and when I open .c I found all the structures written in it. Does Pro*C compiler only compiles EXEC SQL statements which I suppose is not true. Then where all the printfs gone? Were they all converted into structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro*C does not compile anything. It is a C preprocessor. The output C file is compiled with the compiler of your choice.

Comment: Then how I get all the structures in .c file?

Comment: The Pro*C compiler converts the embedded SQL in real C code. The structs are declared in the header files which come with your database (client) installaton.

Comment: so u mean that all my code including the c printfs are converted into the structures in the .c file.

Comment: Not really, Pro*C processes only SQL-related stuff. The rest remains untouched. That's the point of a preprocessor.